# Trouble with parsing PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a html page that I'm trying to use php on. I've got 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html  in the .htaccess file like I read I should have. When I try to access the page in a browser, a dialog box appears that asks whether I would like to save the file or open it in a browser. If I choose to open it in a browser, the page comes up without any css, just very basic html. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run apache. And save the files in the server folder made for it. 
And then you need to go to localhost/your-file

Apache documentation is your friend here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/